# Python Reference to Member Variable Which is Immutable

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with not being able to reference a member variable indirectly.

I have a class with a function which does one thing. This function uses a member variable during its execution, and which member variable it uses is dependent on the input parameter cmd. Here's some code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

    def bar(self, cmd):
        if cmd == "do_this":
            index = self.a
        elif cmd == "do_that":
            index = self.b

        filename = "file-%d.txt" % index
        fp = open("filename", "w")

        # do some more things which depend on and *should* change
        # the value of self.a or self.b

        return
```

Now I understand why this code doesn't do what I want. Because we are using the immutable int type, our variable **index** refers to the value of the member variable **self.a** or **self.b**, not **self.a** or **self.b** *themselves*. By the end of the function, **index** refers to a different valued integer, but **self.a** and **self.b** are unchanged.

I'm obviously thinking too C++-ish. I want something equivalent to

```
index = &(self.a)
filename = "file-%d.txt" % *index
```

How do I accomplish this in a Pythonic way?

Comment: Note that this sort if `if`/`elif` chain is very often best replaced with a dict (`{'do_this': self.a, 'do_that': self.b}`).

Comment: You approach not working doesn't have anything to do with immutability of the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are any number of ways to do this--`setattr` and the attribute name as a string, writing functions or methods which do the setting for each attribute, etc. One that is fairly clear and may be convenient is

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.values = {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

    def bar(self, cmd):
        if cmd == "do_this":
            index = 'a'
        elif cmd == "do_that":
            index = 'b'

        filename = "file-%d.txt" % index
        f = open("filename", "w")

        ...

        self.values[index] = something
```

Your intuition to avoid using attribute names as strings is usually right (although that is easily as good a solution in this particular case), and the stock solution to avoiding looking up attributes and variables by strings is "use a dict".

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, I would simply keep track of the string name of the attribute you're interested in.  something like:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

    def bar(self, cmd):
        if cmd == "do_this":
            index_name = 'a'
        elif cmd == "do_that":
            index_name = 'b'

        index = getattr(self, index_name)

        filename = "file-%d.txt" % index
        fp = open("filename", "w")

        # do some more things which depend on and *should* change
        # the value of index
        #              ^^^^^

        setattr(self, index_name, index)

        return
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using the string id of the member... It just seems a little sloppy to me. 

Is this a pythonic style of coding?

Comment: using `getattr()` and `setattr()` will almost always be preferred over other approaches, which are necessarily less explicit, for the specific case of indirectly operating on object attributes.

Comment: @Harry, Most of the time it's prudent to avoid using `getattr` and `setattr`, but in this case it is fairly benine. It does not make the applicable code very hard to read or understand, and it does not accept arbitrary values for attribute names.

Comment: You can write a proxy class that will at least make the code that manipulates the attributes a little nicer; see my answer.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy, `getattr` and `setattr` are preferred over using a dict?

Comment: @Aaron: Well, only Harry can answer whether a `dict` would be better than object attributes, it may depend on what else those attributes do.  In particular, he's asking "How do I refer to an attribute?", and yes, `getattr`/`setattr` is the most direct way of doing so.  If he had asked "What can I use instead of an attribute?"  then a valid and useful answer might be to use a `dict`.  In python, most attributes are just items in a dict, as in `self.__dict__`, but the attributes could be slots, or they could be attributes defined in a C module; we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep track of strings, you can abstract that away using an attribute proxy class like the following:

```
class AttributeProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, obj_inst, attr_name):
        self.obj_inst, self.attr_name = obj_inst, attr_name

    @property
    def value(self):
        return getattr(self.obj_inst, self.attr_name)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        setattr(self.obj_inst, self.attr_name, value)
```

Usage:

```
class Test(object):
    x = 0
    y = 1

test = Test()

x = AttributeProxy(test, "x")
y = AttributeProxy(test, "y")

print x.value   # 0
x.value += 1
print x.value == y.value
```

Of course, it's still using `getattr()` and `setattr()` behind the scenes, but the client code looks a little nicer. Compare `x.value += 1` to `setattr(obj, "x", getattr(obj, "x") + 1)` frex.

Comment: This strikes me as overengineering. This is more code to understand, debug, and test with no real benefit.

Comment: Entirely possible.  :-)  It would be somewhat nicer if properties didn't have to be bound to object instances.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you're having a problem because the value is immutable, make it mutable! This of course is a complete hack and probably doesn't meet any definition of "Pythonic".

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [0]
        self.b = [0]

    def bar(self, cmd):
        if cmd == "do_this":
            index = self.a
        elif cmd == "do_that":
            index = self.b

        filename = "file-%d.txt" % index[0]
        fp = open("filename", "w")

        # do some more things which depend on and *should* change
        # the value of self.a or self.b
        index[0] = 42

        return
```

Comment: Hehe I thought of this trick too but yeah... not the prettiest code!

Thanks :)

Comment: "Put it in a list" is the stock example of how to add a level of indirection, but I'm not sure I've ever seen the case where I thought it seemed like the best solution.